# Sort matches by the same column value of two users

Tags: mysql, sorting, mariadb, sql-order-by

I want to **sort user interests by matches** with other users. Visual example:

[image]

This image shows this data:

```
array:42 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 82
    "title" => "Travel"
    "status" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 75
    "title" => "Bubble Tea"
    "status" => 1
  ]

...
```

But should show this:

```
array:42 [▼
  0 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 82
    "title" => "Swimming"
    "status" => 1
  ]
  1 => array:3 [▼
    "id" => 75
    "title" => "Birds"
    "status" => 1
  ]

...
```

Since `Swimming`, `Birds`, `Cats`, [...] are mutual interests.

I use `status = -1` for a dislike and `status = 1` for a like. I have the following two tables:

**interests** `[ id , title ]`

**interests_status** `[ id, interest_id, user_id, status ]`

```
SELECT `i`.`id`, `i`.`title`, `a`.`status` 
FROM `interests` as `i` 
INNER JOIN `interests_status` as `a` on `a`.`interest_id` = `i`.`id` 
INNER JOIN `interests_status` as `b` on `b`.`interest_id` = `i`.`id` 
WHERE `a`.`user_id` = 10 
GROUP BY `i`.`id` 
ORDER BY b.user_id = 11 AND a.status = b.status DESC
```

How can I priotize the results that all my matches (both likes and dislikes) with this user are displayed first? I tried a second join to the same table to reference to me (user id 11) but this doesn't work.

Comment: The [image](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) is not helpful, Sample data and desired results however *would* be.

Comment: I thought my question was clear and this image helps to visualize. I edited and added some data that represents the image.